# Only show object once and count it

Tags: django

after searching for a long time without getting an answer i'm gonna try here.

I'm working on django. My project is a mailling system, each time a recipient open a mail i know what mail get opened who opened it and when it get opened.
Here is the table where i display the stats. It shows me every recipient and the datetime, but my problem is that i want to see every recipient once, and then to show how many times it get opened.

```
        <tbody>
          {% for stat_mail in stat_mail %}
            {% ifchanged stat_mail.recipient %}
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ stat_mail.recipient }}</td>
                  <td>{{ stat_mail.datetime }}</td>
                  <td>{{ stat_mail.recipient_set.all|length }}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endifchanged %}
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

For example : 
Test 1 opened the mail at 5PM and at 8PM, so the table should display

Test 1 / 5PM, 8PM / 2

The name of the recipient, the date of the oppening, and the number of oppening.

Sorry for the bad english but i'm french :)

Hope someone can help me, if u have other question or need more code just ask.

Thanks a lot !

EDIT : My models.py

```
class Recipient(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name= ('Nom'), null=True, blank=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name= ('Prénom'), null=True, blank=True)
mail = models.EmailField(verbose_name= ('Adresse du destinataire'))
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s' % (self.name, self.first_name)

class Tag(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
recipients = models.ManyToManyField(Recipient, verbose_name='Destinataires', null=False, blank=False, related_name="tags")
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Mail(models.Model):
subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name= ('Sujet'), blank=False, null=False)
content = HTMLField(verbose_name= ('Contenu'), blank=False, null=False, default=' ')
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, verbose_name= ('Destinataires'), null=True, blank=True, related_name='mails')
recipients = models.ManyToManyField(Recipient, verbose_name='Destinataires', null=True, blank=True, related_name='mails')
date_create = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name= ('Date de création'), default=datetime.now, blank=False, editable = False)
writer = models.ForeignKey(Intervenant, verbose_name= ('Personne écrivant la compagne'), null=True, blank=True) 
holding = models.ForeignKey(Holding, verbose_name= ('Organisation'),related_name= ('Questionnaire_mail'), null=False, blank=False, default=1, editable = False)
sended = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = ('Compagne envoyée ?'), default=False, editable=False)
opened = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=("Nombre totale d'ouverture"), default=0, editable=False)
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Destinataire de Test', blank=True, null=True)

date_create = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name= ('Date de création'), default=datetime.now, blank=False, editable = False)
date_sent = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name= ('Date de création'), blank=True, null=True, editable = False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.subject

class Mail_Stats(models.Model):
mail = models.ForeignKey(Mail, verbose_name= ('Compagne'), related_name='mails_stats')
recipient = models.ForeignKey(Recipient, verbose_name= ('Destinataires'), null=True, blank=True, related_name='mails_stats')
datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name= ('Date et Heure'), auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: So, what do you see instead of what you were expecting? And it would help to show the models.

Comment: The table should show the differents recipients (the one who aren't repeated)
And count how many times one recipient opened the mail
I added my models on the question
Actually it shows the recipient everytime they are in the table and it didn't count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prepare your data in the view and then pass it to the template. Something like this (untested):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Mail_Stats

def stats_view(request):
    recipient_list = [] # this will be put in the template context

    current_recipient = None
    cnt_read = 0
    read_datetime_list = []

    for stat in Mail_Stats.objects.all().order_by('mail', 'recipient'):
        if stat.recipient != current_recipient:
            if cnt_read > 0:
                recipient_list.append({
                    'recipient': current_recipient,
                    'read_datetime_list': read_datetime_list,
                    'cnt_read': cnt_read
                })
            current_recipient = stat.recipient
            cnt_read = 0
            read_datetime_list = []
        cnt_read += 1
        read_datetime_list.append(stat.datetime)

    # add last recipient to the list, if not None
    if current_recipient is not None:
        recipient_list.append({
            'recipient': current_recipient,
            'read_datetime_list': read_datetime_list,
            'cnt_read': cnt_read
        })

    render(request, 'mail_stats.html', { 'recipient_list': recipient_list })
```

Then in your template you could simply do something like this:

```
<tbody>
    {% for r in recipient_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ r.recipient }}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                {% for dt in r.read_datetime_list %}
                    <li>{{ dt }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>{{ r.cnt_read }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

The important thing is: do not struggle doing complex stuff in templates, keep them only for presentation purposes. Move all logic in the view (or models, or utility modules), there you can leverage all the power of Python.

Comment: A better data structure would be a dictionary; with the key being the recipient.

Comment: It works thanks, the only thing is that the last recipient in the table don't get into the list so doesn't show on the table.

Because it never goes into :        
   if stat.recipient != current_recipient:
If someone have an idea how to fix it ?

But really thanks it helped me a lot !

Comment: EDIT : I changed the code and just put the .append at the end, so everytime the list get a new entry, and then on the template i just used a ifchanged. But i think that a better solution exists

Comment: I edited the code to take into account the last recipient of the queryset. Sorry for the bug on the first version, every code should be tested ;).

Comment: It works thanks, and you don't need to be sorry for that it worked :)